# Google sheets - sequential unique ID

Tags: google-sheets

I need a simple sequential unique ID.

[image]

The UNIQUE_ID column must be unique, and needs to be filled in for new rows if they are added. New rows can be added anywhere in the sheet, and I do not want the unique ID of any of the previously existing rows to be changed, so it cannot simply be based on the row index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Google Script then you can try below:

```
function onEdit(){

uniqueId();

}

function uniqueId() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1')//change sheet name per your requirement;
  const lr = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  const  idRange = ss.getRange(2,6,lr-1).getValues() //change range per your requirement;
  const  dataRange = ss.getRange(2,1,lr-1).getValues() //change range per your requirement;

  for (i=0; i<dataRange.length; i++){

    if(dataRange[i] !=''){

      var maxId = Math.max.apply(null, ss.getRange(2,6,lr-1).getValues());

      if(idRange[i] == '')
      
      ss.getRange(i+2,6).setValue(maxId+1);

      
    }

  }
 
}
```

> Remove the **onEdit** Function if you do want to run it on every edit

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a mega-formula that applies various math to word lengths, ASCII codes at different positions and more:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,LEFT(TEXT(TRUNC((MMULT(IFERROR(CODE(SPLIT(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(.)","$1|"))&REPT("|",MAX(LEN(A2:A))-LEN(A2:A)),"|",1,0)),0),SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(A2:A))+1,1,1,0))/CODE(MID(A2:A,1,1))*CODE(MID(A2:A&" ",2,1))-IFERROR(CODE(MID(A2:A,3,1))/(CODE(RIGHT(A2:A))-(CODE(LEFT(A2:A))/IFERROR(CODE(MID(A2:A,4,1)),13))-(CODE(LEFT(A2:A))/IFERROR(CODE(MID(A2:A,6,1)),17))),7)),10)*10^8,"0000000000"),8)))`

Applying it against 5000 of the most common words in English plus your shortlist, I worked it out to where there were no duplicates (i.e., every word was assigned a unique code). **NOTE:** While the generated IDs are all unique, they are *not* sequential. If that is necessary, this approach will not work for your purposes (but I'm submitting it because it may address the needs of future site visitors).

As written, the word list is in A2:A. The formula would go in the Row-2 cell of the column where you want the codes.

See if that works for you.

SIDE NOTE: I find myself curious as to why one would need a unique code if the words themselves are all unique.